# how to read a XML string value with leading space in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to store the value of userId as `"    XYZ"` but when after executing the below code got output as `"XYZ"`.
Want to store the value with leading space.

```
Declare @xml    Nvarchar(100), 
        @hDoc   Int,
        @user   Nvarchar(30)


SET @XML= '<ROOT><DETAIL ID ="1" name ="ABC" userId="    XYZ" /></ROOT>'


EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @xml 

    SELECT  @user = userId
    FROM    OPENXML(@hDoc, '/ROOT/DETAIL')   
    WITH    ( userId Nvarchar(30) )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

SELECT @user
```

Comment: Why are you using those old system procedure? SQL Server has supported XQUERY since *at least* SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to parse the input XML using a variable of `XML` data type and a combination of `nodes()` and `value()` methods:

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = N'<ROOT><DETAIL ID ="1" name ="ABC" userId="    XYZ" /></ROOT>'

SELECT d.a.value('@userId', 'nvarchar(30)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/ROOT/DETAIL') d(a)
```

Using this approach you may parse more complex XML data and get `userId`'s as rows in a table:

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = N'<ROOT>
   <DETAIL ID ="1" name ="ABC" userId="    XYZ" />
   <DETAIL ID ="2" name ="ABC" userId="    123" />
</ROOT>'

SELECT d.a.value('@userId', 'nvarchar(30)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/ROOT/DETAIL') d(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just add space before `userID`, you will get desired result.

```
SELECT  @user = ' ' + userId
FROM    OPENXML(@hDoc, '/ROOT/DETAIL')   
WITH    ( userId Nvarchar(30) )
```

Check answer on [DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=23537a8715fedea4ed996d0c6697d17e)

Comment: I don't want to add in extra space. need to fetch the same value passed in userId tag.

Comment: First of all, when you ask question, post what you really want... After Zhorov updated question, I see what you need...

Answer (score 0):

As @Larnu pointed out:

Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is better to use XQuery language, based on the w3c standards, while dealing with the XML data type.
Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL
Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
It is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.

One single XQuery `.value()` method call gives you all what you need.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'<ROOT><DETAIL ID ="1" name ="ABC" userId="    XYZ" /></ROOT>'
    , @user nvarchar(30);

SET @user = (SELECT @xml.value('(/ROOT/DETAIL/@userId)[1]', 'nvarchar(30)'));
SELECT @user;
```